# Not able to add Users to Site Collection in SharePoint 2013

Tags: site-collection, user-profile-service, site

I am having big issues in adding users to a site collection to giving them access.

Let me describe to you my problem:

1. I have created a site collection and can set the site collection
   administrators.
2. To even allow the site administrators access I have to set Everyone
   in the User Policy in Managed Web Application. If I change this,
   everyone is not able to access the site. Why it is this way, I do
   not know.
3. User Profile Synchronization Service is set to Active Directory
   Import and ALL Services are running. I have left User Properties to
   default and thus deliberately have not changed them
4. Leaving access to Everyone through User Policy, I can then log on to
   the site. Going to site settings, and then to Site Permissions,
   searching for a user to add to the site, returns nothing. There are
   no users coming up.
5. However, in Central Administration I can see ALL my users from
   Active Directory.

So, can someone please if they can answer me the following questions:

1. How do I ensure that I can see any user imported into SharePoint
   2013 are visible in any Site Collection?
2. How do I ensure that a Site Collection Administrator set during Site
   Collection creation can get access without having to set User Policy
   to Everyone, or is this the way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion for the first question

- Turn on the search service application from the Central Administrator and create a Search page.
- start a full import of AD users from user profiles an property section.
- now go the the search page and try searching for a username that already exist in your AD account.

If the users you type exist in the search, that me he/she got access to the site

Comment: This only proves that I can see them in CA. My issue is that I cannot see them in the picker to add them via site permissions

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some where between syncing the users and web.config. I restarted everything by changing the syncing of users from Windows Authentication to FBA and made sure this works, and then created a new site using LDAP with FBA and it allowed me this time to set a site admin and login as a user.